# Google Reader API: How can I remove a feed from a single folder?

Tags: google-reader

So let's say I have the following setup in Google Reader

**Folder One**

- Engadget
- Gizmodo

**Folder Two**

- Engadget
- webOSroundup

Using the Google Reader API, I would like to remove engadget from only Folder One...leaving Folder Two untouched.

I know how to pull engadget out of Folder One and leave him ungrouped, but if I unsubscribe it takes it out of both folders.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see how this is programming-related. Could you clarify?

Comment: I added some clarification to show that I am talking about using the Google Reader API...not just the website.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because Google Reader no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a subscription from a folder you'll need to send a `POST` request to `/reader/api/0/subscription/edit` with the parameters:

- `s=feed/http://www.engadget.com/rss.xml`: the feed stream ID
- `ac=edit`: the action type (other possible values are `subscribe` and `unsubscribe`)
- `r=user/-/label/Folder One`: the folder you wish to remove it from (you can use the `a` parameter to add it to a folder; you can repeat either one more than once to add/remove it from multiple folders)
- `T=token`: the usual action token used for all state-changing requests

Answer (score -1):

Click on the down-arrow next to `Engadget` (in either **Folder One** or **Folder Two**). Uncheck the option for **Folder One**.

Alternative: Under the `Manage subscriptions >>` you can find your subscriptions and remove **Folder One** from the `Engadget` folders by clicking on the `Change Folders...` drop-down.